# be careful about . .

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Is "be careful about" used properly in the following?

> Be careful about the tricks of cunning businesspeople.

Or should I say:

> Take care not to fall for the tricks of cunning businesspeople.

Or,

> Watch out for the tricks of cunning businesspeople.

Answer (score 2):

If you said "Be careful about the tricks of cunning businesspeople," I would understand what you meant, but it doesn't really sound right to me.

"Be careful about something" means "Don't make any errors doing something." You would say it in a sentence like, "Be careful about carrying those expensive plates," which would mean "Don't drop or break the plates."

The meaning you're looking for in this sentence isn't "Don't make a mistake while you're doing something" but rather "Beware of something that someone else is doing." In my opinion, "Watch out for the tricks of cunning businesspeople" captures this meaning perfectly.

The sentence "Take care not to fall for the tricks of cunning businesspeople" is also correct, but it is a bit wordy.